# Xgboost not running with Callibrated Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying to run XGboost with with calibrated classifier, below is the snippet of code where I am facing the error:

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import numpy as np

x_train =np.array([1,2,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,10,]).reshape(-1,1)
y_train = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3])

x_cfl=XGBClassifier(n_estimators=1)
x_cfl.fit(x_train,y_train)
sig_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(x_cfl, method="sigmoid")
sig_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: predict_proba() got an unexpected keyword argument 'X'"
```

Full Trace:

```
TypeError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-08dd0b4ae8aa> in <module>
----> 1 sig_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    309                 parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)
    310 
--> 311                 self.calibrated_classifiers_ = parallel(
    312                     delayed(_fit_classifier_calibrator_pair)(
    313                         clone(base_estimator), X, y, train=train, test=test,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1039             # remaining jobs.
   1040             self._iterating = False
-> 1041             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1042                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1043 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    857                 return False
    858             else:
--> 859                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    860                 return True
    861 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    775         with self._lock:
    776             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 777             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    778             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    779             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209         if callback:
    210             callback(result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571         # arguments in memory
--> 572         self.results = batch()
    573 
    574     def get(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    260         # change the default number of processes to -1
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    260         # change the default number of processes to -1
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    220     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    221         with config_context(**self.config):
--> 222             return self.function(*args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py in _fit_classifier_calibrator_pair(estimator, X, y, train, test, supports_sw, method, classes, sample_weight)
    443     n_classes = len(classes)
    444     pred_method = _get_prediction_method(estimator)
--> 445     predictions = _compute_predictions(pred_method, X[test], n_classes)
    446 
    447     sw = None if sample_weight is None else sample_weight[test]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py in _compute_predictions(pred_method, X, n_classes)
    499         (X.shape[0], 1).
    500     """
--> 501     predictions = pred_method(X=X)
    502     if hasattr(pred_method, '__name__'):
    503         method_name = pred_method.__name__

TypeError: predict_proba() got an unexpected keyword argument 'X'
```

I am quite surprised by this, as it was running for me till yesterday, same code is running when I use some other Classifier.

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import numpy as np

x_train = np.array([1,2,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,10,]).reshape(-1,1)
y_train = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3])


x_cfl=LGBMClassifier(n_estimators=1)
x_cfl.fit(x_train,y_train)
sig_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(x_cfl, method="sigmoid")
sig_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Output:

```
CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=LGBMClassifier(n_estimators=1))
```

Is there a problem with my Xgboost installation?? I use conda for installation and last I remember I had uninstalled xgboost yesterday and installed it again.

my xgboost version:

> 1.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the problem comes from XGBoost.
It's explained here: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/6555

XGBoost defined:

`predict_proba(self, data, ...`

instead of:

`predict_proba(self, X, ...`

And since sklearn 0.24 calls `clf.predict_proba(X=X)`, an exception is thrown.

Here is an idea to fix the problem without changing the version of your packages: Create a class that inherits `XGBoostClassifier` to override `predict_proba` with the right argument names and call `super()`.

Comment: Great, following the PR thread it looks like the fix is in for xgboost version >= 1.3.2 (sklearn any version).

Comment: I get exactly the same error for catboost (0.24.4):  TypeError: predict_proba() got an unexpected keyword argument 'X'. Any idea how to fix it?  @6761646f6e do you have a template for the new class that inherits from XGBoostClassifier?

Comment: Hello, my new class that inherits from XGBoostClassifier contains: `def predict_proba(self, X, ...): return super(CustomXGBClassifier, self).predict_proba(X, ...)`.
I also noticed problems with the `kwargs` attribute that would require you to override `get_params` if you need to `sklearn.base.clone` your models.

Answer (score 2):

It's fixed now, seems like there is a bug in scikit-learn= 0.24

I downgraded to 0.22.2.post1 and it was fixed!

Comment: Please accept your own answer so that it is visibly useful for others in the future.

Comment: If you've identified the bug, is there an Issue at scikit-learn's github?

Comment: Yes, there is a bug,

Answer (score 1):

Th best way is to upgrade your xgboost

run the following from the jupyter notebook

```
pip install xgboost --upgrade
```