# TypeError with Sklear XGBoost and Sklearn Calibrated Classifier CV

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, calibration, xgbclassifier

I'm trying to calibrate the output probabilities from a XGBClassifier.

I've provided the sample code,

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_var, y_var, test_size = 0.2, shuffle = False)
new_mod2 = xgb.XGBClassifier(scale_pos_weight = 1, eta = 0.3, nthread = 10, learning_rate = 0.05, max_depth = 2, n_estimators = 180, objective = 'binary:logistic' )  
calibrated = CalibratedClassifierCV( base_estimator = new_mod2,method = 'Isotonic', cv=3)
calibrated.fit(X = x_train, y = y_train)
```

But when running the calibrated.fit() function, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: predict_proba() got an unexpected keyword argument 'X'
```

It's my understanding that the calibratedclassifiercv should work with the sklearn xgboost wrapper.

Yet the calibrated classifier cv seems to be passing the incorrect variable to the predict_proba() method of xgboost.

Is there any reason this might be occurring?

Comment: Please provide the whole error traceback.  And it would be helpful if you can provide a minimal reproducible example: here, that would mean including a data sample that demonstrates this error (either a small simplified version of yours, or perhaps one of the sklearn builtin datasets).

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/65517931/10495893

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xgboost not running with Callibrated Classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65517931/xgboost-not-running-with-callibrated-classifier)

Comment: After continuing to test, I found that given enough data and setting the objective function to logloss, the xgboost achieved fairly well calibrated posterior probabilities. Atleast based on viewing the calibration plot.