# Using pipeline classifier inside of CalibratedClassifierCV

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, xgboost

I am trying to train an XGBoost classfier. The target variable `y` is binary.

**DATA** (Couldn't find a sample dataset to make this completely reproducible. Sorry about that).

`X_train, X_validate, X_test` (contain numerical and categorical data)

`y_train, y_validate, y_test` (the values are binary 1/0).

**PREPROCESSOR**.

```
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='MISSING')),
        ('encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])
    
    
    numerical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[  
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value=-999))])
    
    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        remainder='passthrough',
        transformers=[
            ('cat', categorical_transformer, selector(dtype_include="object")),
            ('num', numerical_transformer, selector(dtype_exclude="object"))
        ])
```

**MODEL**.

```
best_clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', 
                        xgb.XGBClassifier(
                        seed=42,
                        objective='binary:logistic',
                        missing=-999,
                        ## optimal params
                        learning_rate = 0.1))])

best_clf.fit(X_train, y_train, 
            classifier__early_stopping_rounds=10,
            classifier__eval_metric='aucpr',
            classifier__eval_set=[(X_validate_preprocessed, y_validate)],
            classifier__verbose=True)
```

Everyting works fine so far. I now have model. But I want to **calibrate** this model.

**CALIBRATION**.

I tried:

```
best_clf_calib = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                                ('calibrator', CalibratedClassifierCV(
                                                    base_estimator=best_clf.named_steps.classifier,
                                                    cv='prefit', 
                                                    method='isotonic'))])

best_clf_calib.fit(X_validate, y_validate)
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: predict_proba() got an unexpected keyword argument 'X'
```

**Question**: How specifically should I set the `base_estimator` parameter in `CalibratedClassifierCV`?. I tried setting

```
base_estimator = best_clf
```

But in that case, it seems that the pipeline gets run twice. Here is a diagram of the pipeline steps.

[image]

Comment: Please check if this solution works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65517931/xgboost-not-running-with-callibrated-classifier

Comment: @Anu: Yes, downgrading the sklearn version worked. Thanks. If you put that down as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xgboost not running with Callibrated Classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65517931/xgboost-not-running-with-callibrated-classifier)

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to downgrade sklearn.

I believe that the problem comes from XGBoost.
It's explained here: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/6555

XGBoost defined:

`predict_proba(self, data, ...`

instead of:

`predict_proba(self, X, ...`

And since sklearn 0.24 calls `clf.predict_proba(X=X)`, an exception is thrown.

Here is an idea to fix the problem without changing the version of your packages: Create a class that inherits `XGBoostClassifier` to override `predict_proba` with the right argument names and call `super()`.

Comment: Please do not post the exact same answer to multiple questions: if the questions are duplicates, flag/vote them as such; and if they are not, then try to tailor your answer to the different questions.